# Using File chooser to get the absolute path of a file into a jTextField

Tags: swing, browser, jtextfield, jfilechooser

I have made an application to browse through files and get the absolute path of the file into a text field. although I can browse through files when i click the browse button the file path doesn't appear on the text field. Can you help me with identifying the error.
Thanks in advance

```
private void browse3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JFileChooser Chooser = new JFileChooser();
        Chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        Chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int result = Chooser.showDialog(this,"Open/Save");
        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = Chooser.getSelectedFile();
            resultFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error in next. You select file but you don't set its path to your `JTextField`. You need to use [`setText(String text)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) method of your textField. Read [tutorial for TextFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). It will be looking like next:

```
 File file = Chooser.getSelectedFile();
 textField.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

here `textField` its your `JTextField` for path of file.